# Debugging when Blazor CSS Isolation doesn't work

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor, migration

I recently migrated a project originally templated in AspNetCore 7.0 Blazor WASM to AspNetCore 8.0 following [Microsoft's guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).  Things work, except when the pages load, the browser can't find the "{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" file that is [supposed to be generated according to the docs on Blazor CSS Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling).  I want to debug why this file isn't generated, but I can't find anything on what to check when that file is NOT magically generating.  (NOTE:  [The base path for static web assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling) has not been changed, [automatic bundling is not disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling), and [CSS isolation is not disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling).)

What do I check when the {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css file is not generated?

Comment: If everything is ok,try cleam the .vs folder and reopen the project in visual studio